# Bad auto formatting in razor page file for <text> blocks - VS2022

Tags: javascript, .net-core, razor, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

In a razor page file (.cshtml), when I use for example `;` or `{`, in  `@<text>` block or anything except for razor syntax, then the file is auto-formatted, the same as if I use `Ctrl+K+D`.

The issue is that EACH time my file is formatted, EVERY content inside a `@<text>` block will be indented.

Example:

```
.OnDone(@<text>
    foo();
 </text>)
```

after writing the second `;` it became (and all other `@<text>` block in my file)

```
.OnDone(@<text>
        foo();
        foo2();
</text>)
```

I already deactivated the option `Use adaptative formatting`.
I tried in *Options* > *Text Editor* > *JavaScript/TypeScript* > *Formatting* and unchecked everthing in *Automatic Formatting* but without success.

Important to mention that this behavior is only in **VS2022** and not in VS2019.

Comment: Well, Razor page formatting is terrible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed with update 17.3 of VS2022.

See [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#1730--visual-studio-2022-version-173) at section "Razor (ASP.NET Core) Editor".